# How to use startWith operator only once in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is it possible to have `startWith` run only once?

In my [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nufbhd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I have a button that trigger a `Subject`.

In the `constructor` I subscribe to the `Subject` in order to get the results.

In the pipe of the `Subject` I return the results with a delay of 4 seconds (http fake).

I also add `startWith` to pass to subscribe function the value of `pending: true` and end up with `endWith` with value of `pending: false`.

I love this syntax of `{ pending: true }` and `{ pending: false }` by passing object and not callback function.

But how to make `startWith` happens only once? is it possible? I don't want to have `pending: true` each time. only once.

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { of, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, delay, exhaustMap, startWith, endWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   in app!

   <button (click)="load()">load</button>
  
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  loadSubject = new Subject();

  load$ = this.loadSubject.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('in load!');
    }),
    exhaustMap(() =>
      of({ items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] })
        .pipe(delay(4 * 1000))
        .pipe(startWith({ pending: true }), endWith({ pending: false }))
    )
  );

  constructor() {
    this.load$.subscribe((r) => {
      console.log(r);
    });
  }

  load() {
    this.loadSubject.next(null);
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe with `.pipe(distinctUntilChanged((prev, curr) => prev. pending === curr. pending))`

Answer (score 0):

Map operators have an index parameter that let you know the number of request that was made. If you want to do something different on the first request you just check if the index is zero.

```js
  load$ = this.loadSubject.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('in load!');
    }),
    exhaustMap((_, i) =>
      i === 0
        ? of({ items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] })
            .pipe(delay(4 * 1000))
            .pipe(startWith({ pending: true }), endWith({ pending: false }))
        : of({ items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] })
            .pipe(delay(4 * 1000))
            .pipe(endWith({ pending: false }))
    )
  );
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-95neuw?file=src/app/app.component.ts